# Onchange method not saving

Tags: odoo

So I have an onchange method that looks like it's working. When I enter a new value in the onchange field it triggers my method that writes a value in another field.

Example code:

```
@api.onchange('xx_next_air_shipment')
def _onchange_air_shipment(self):
    self.xx_next_air_value = self.xx_next_air_shipment * self.xx_price_unit
```

On screen everything looks correct, but when I press save the value seem to get lost?

I then tried editing the write method, I debugged it and saw that the correct values where in the parameter so I just returned a the write method with the correct values but it still didn't save it to the database:

```
@api.one
def write(self, vals):
    from openerp.pydev import pydevd
    return self.write(vals)
```

Comment: Isn't that `self.write(vals)` call causing an infinite loop?

Comment: am agree with Daniel, you need call super in order to save the record.

Answer (score 0):

Update that method code,

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    from openerp.pydev import pydevd
    return super(class_name,self).write(vals)
```

@Daniel Reis is right your method's result turns into the infinite loop.

Comment: Agreed but the question was more related to why it isn't saving the values in the database. Since I normally shouldn't be overriding the write method. I've tried using the updated write method but still doesn't save the values.

Comment: it's because you are calling write method from it self. it won't perform anything in your case unless you call super method.

Comment: If you want to save that data then you need to call any other method and inside that you need to write that statements which can save/update data.

Comment: I've tried it with the adjust method (calling super and write) but that gave the same problem, again I don't need the actual write method, it was just to check what values where in the parameters. The problem was that my field was readonly. This worked in version 7 but it seems in version 8 you cannot perform an onchange method on a field that is readonly.

Comment: readonly fields never pass onward to the any methods for storing in odoo-8